# ReactJS modify parent state from child component

Tags: state, reactjs

I'm trying to remove an item from my state array when clicked. At the moment I have an onclick listener which calls a function passed into the props. However I get a warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance. See App... and it does not remove the item.

Thanks for any help regarding this issue! It has pretty much ground my progress to a halt.

```
(function (React) {

var data = [
    'Go to work',
    'Play Albion Online',
    'Keep learning React'
]

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: []}
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.state.data = data;
    },
    removeItem: function (i) {
        console.log(i);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
        <ToDoList onRemoveItem={this.removeItem} tasks={this.state.data} />
        )
    }
});

var ToDoList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        var scope = this;

        var tasks = this.props.tasks.map(function (task, i) {
            return <ToDo onClick={scope.props.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)} key={task} task={task} />
        });

        return (
        <ul>
            {tasks}
        </ul>
        )
    }
});

var ToDo = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.task}</li>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('example'));
})(React);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React actually auto-binds methods to the current component:

http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html

In the TodoList component, rather than:

```
scope.props.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)
```

Try:

```
scope.props.onRemoveItem.bind(null, i)
```

By providing `null` instead of `this` you'll allow React to do its own thing. Also you need to actually use the onClick handler:

```
<li onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.task}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks man, the error is gone but it is still not console logging anything :/

Comment: You should also call `onClick` from ToDo component: http://jsfiddle.net/n8cph674/

Comment: Cool its working, but isnt it kinda annoying to have to put a click on your li, which calls a prop function on its parent, which then again calls a prop function on ITS parent, WHICH THEN calls a function that finally does what you want. What if the nesting was deeper? It would become madness.

Comment: Remember that React is only a rendering library. For complex situations, you want some form of application framework. There's no "right way". Pick whichever framework/architecture you find that fits your use case best. Most designs though will pull data out of the components. Your component would fetch the initial data then listen for updates. The immediate parent/child is really the only sane exception where coupling makes sense. Eg a List component and a ListItem component have a logical relationship. The usual recommendation is to use a Flux implementation for your application architecture.

Comment: Your ToDo component is very simple and likely doesn't need to actually be a component, unless you plan to reuse it with other components. You could just as easily use <li> within your map function instead of <ToDo>. If you plan to reuse the ToDo component elsewhere, then this wouldn't work.