# React How to change child state based on parent function

Tags: reactjs

I'm building React project(magazine) for learning purposes. I'm stuck on making counter in my shopping cart. Each product item has it's quantity. Each time I click on *add to cart* button, it increases by 1. When I click close button, item dissapears but it's quantity is saved, though I want it to set to 0. So the next time I click *add to cart*, it's quantity start from 0 again. 
Sounds easy, but I'm stuck. Seems I've tried almost everything I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Here is the main component:

```
`class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleAddToCart = this.handleAddToCart.bind(this);
        this.itemRemove = this.itemRemove.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          products: {products: []},
          cart: [],
          quantity: 0,
          itemQ: 0,
        };
      }

    handleAddToCart(selectedProducts) {
    let cartItems = this.state.cart;
    let productID = selectedProducts.id;
    let productQty = selectedProducts.quantity;

    if(this.checkProduct(productID)) {
      let index = cartItems.findIndex(x => x.id == productID);
      cartItems[index].quantity = productQty;
      this.setState({
        cart: cartItems,
      });
    } else {
      cartItems.push(selectedProducts);
    }
    this.setState({
      cart: cartItems,
    });
  };



itemRemove(id, amount, e) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    let test = amount;
    let index = cart.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
    let productQty = amount;
    cart[index].quantity = Number(productQty);
    cart.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      cart: cart,
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemQty: 0
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  };

checkProduct(productID) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    return cart.some(function(item) {
      return item.id === productID;
    });
  }

render() {
    return(
      <div className="main">
        <Products
          addToCart={this.handleAddToCart} 
          productsList={this.state.products}
          itemQuantity={this.state.itemQuantity}
        />
        <Cart 
          cartItems={this.state.cart}
          itemRemove={this.itemRemove}
          quantity={this.state.itemQuantity}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Cart Component(where I add and remove item from shopping cart):

```
render() {
        let cartItems;
        cartItems = this.state.cart.map(product => {
            return(

            <CSSTransition key={product.id} classNames={'fade'} timeout={{enter:500, exit: 300}}>       
                <div className="product-item-wrapper">
                    <div className="product-item">
                        <div 
                            className="item-remove"
                            onClick={this.props.itemRemove.bind(this, product.id, product.quantity)}
                        >
                        </div>
                        <div className="item-img">
                            {product.thumb}
                        </div>
                        <div className="item-info">
                            <p className="item-name">{product.title}</p>
                            <p className="item-desc">{product.style}</p>
                            <p className="item-quantity">Quantity: {product.quantity}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="price">
                            <p>$ {product.price}</p>
                        </div>
```

Product Component(where I add items to shopping cart by clicking 'add to cart' button:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedProduct: {},
            isAdded: false,
            itemQuantity: 0
        };
    }

addToCart(style, title, price, id, thumb, quantity) {
        this.setState(
            {
                selectedProduct: {
                    style: style,
                    title: title,
                    price: price,
                    id: id,
                    thumb: thumb,
                    quantity: quantity
                },
            },
            function() {
                this.props.addToCart(this.state.selectedProduct);
            }
        );
        this.setState(
            {
            isAdded: true,
            itemQuantity: this.state.itemQuantity + 1,
            },
        );
    }

render() {

        const {id, title, style, price, currency, installments} = this.props;
        const quantity = this.state.itemQuantity;


        return(
            <div className="product">

                <div 
                    className="buy-btn"
                    onClick={this.addToCart.bind(
                        this,
                        style,
                        title,
                        price,
                        id,
                        thumb,
                        quantity
                    )}
                >
                    Add to cart
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I tried so many things. When I remove item, and then add it to cart again, its quantity is not set to 0. Obvious why...because it depends on state value(which is in Product component). So I have to set this state to 0 every time I remove item from shopping cart. Simple...but in order to do that I have to pass it to parent component by callback function. Then change this quantity and pass it again to Product component. But when I do this, cart items have the same counter to products, not independent to each one. I'm confused, stuck and don't know what to do. Hope you will help[image: Area where I stuck]

Comment: Just pass a function's reference as a prop to the child. `<Child parentFunction={this.myFunction} />`

Comment: If you mean to pass itemRemove function from parent component(App,js) to Product component as a prop, there would be another problem. Function itemRemove is called in Cart component onClick as a prop from main, App component. So how would I call itemRemove function from Cart component then if it's rendering in App but the function itself would be in Product? Sorry, it's a bit confused, I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my issue this way:
At first I got rid of all states in Product component, because they were of no use in my case. In Product component I only call AddToCart function from props.

```
this.props.addToCart({ 
style: style, 
title: title, 
price: price, 
id: id, 
thumb: thumb 
});
```

I removed **quantity** variable from this function as an argument because state in parent component(App) would be enough. In App I change **handleAddToCart** and **itemRemove** functions:

```
handleAddToCart(selectedProduct) { 
let cartItems = this.state.cart; 
let productID = selectedProduct.id; 
if(this.checkProduct(productID)) { 
let index = cartItems.findIndex(x => x.id == productID); 
cartItems[index].quantity += 1; 
this.setState({ 
cart: cartItems, 
}); 
} else { 
selectedProduct.quantity = 0; 
cartItems.push(selectedProduct); 
} 
this.setState({ 
cart: cartItems, 
}); 
};
```

in itemRemove I just changed one line then: `cart[index].quantity = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions for this, Fastest would be to create a function in the parent component that changes the state in question. you will then be able to inject the function into the child component through the constructor. Then simply call the injected function whenever you need the parent state to change!

Second but better would be to use [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux)

Possible duplicate of [ReactJS modify parent state from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524751/reactjs-modify-parent-state-from-child-component) ?

Comment: It should be noted that your first solution would still apply if Redux was to be implemented. You'd still need to pass action creators down through props so that the proper state change could be dispatched.